# Returning Dynamic Content-Type via AWS API Gateway and Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, content-type, aws-api-gateway

I want to use an AWS API Gateway as a proxy for fetching files from an S3 bucket and returning them to the client. I'm using a Lambda function to talk to S3 and send the file to the client via the AWS API Gateway. I've rad that the best way to do this is to use a "Lambda proxy integration" so the entire request gets piped to Lambda without any modification. But if I do that then I can't setup an Integration Response for the resulting response from my Lambda function. So all the client gets is JSON.

It seems there should be a way for the API Gateway to take the JSON and transform the request to the proper response for the client but I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen. There are lots of examples that point to setting a content-type on the response from the API Gateway manually but I need to set the content-type header to whatever the file type is.

Also for images and binary formats my Lambda function is returning a base64 encoded string and the property `isBase64Encoded` set to `true`. When I go to the "Binary Support" section and specify something like `image/*` as a content type that should be returned as binary, it doesn't work. I only have success by setting the Binary Support content type to `*/*` (aka everything) which won't work for non-binary content types.

What am I missing and why does this seem so difficult?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out API Gateway isn't the problem. My Lambda function wasn't returning proper headers.

For handling binary responses I found you need to set Binary Support content type to `*/*` (aka everything) and then have your Lambda function return the property `isBase64Encoded` set to `true`. Responses that are base64 encoded and indicated as such will be decoded and served as binary while other requests will be returned as is.

Here's a simple Gist for a Lambda function that takes a given path and reads the file from S3 and returns it via the API Gateway:

```
/**
 * This is a simple AWS Lambda function that will look for a given file on S3 and return it
 * passing along all of the headers of the S3 file. To make this available via a URL use
 * API Gateway with an AWS Lambda Proxy Integration.
 * 
 * Set the S3_REGION and S3_BUCKET global parameters in AWS Lambda
 * Make sure the Lambda function is passed an object with `{ pathParameters : { proxy: 'path/to/file.jpg' } }` set
 */

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = function( event, context, callback ) {
    var region = process.env.S3_REGION;
    var bucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET;
    var key = decodeURI( event.pathParameters.proxy );

    // Basic server response
    /*
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        },
        body: "Hello world!",
    };
    callback( null, response );
    */

    // Fetch from S3
    var s3 = new AWS.S3( Object.assign({ region: region }) );
    return s3.makeUnauthenticatedRequest(
        'getObject',
        { Bucket: bucket, Key: key },
        function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }

            var isBase64Encoded = false;
            if ( data.ContentType.indexOf('image/') > -1 ) {
                isBase64Encoded = true;
            }

            var encoding = '';
            if ( isBase64Encoded ) {
                encoding = 'base64'
            }
            var resp = {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': data.ContentType,
                },
                body: new Buffer(data.Body).toString(encoding),
                isBase64Encoded: isBase64Encoded
            };

            callback(null, resp);
        }
    );
};
```

via https://gist.github.com/kingkool68/26aa7a3641a3851dc70ce7f44f589350