# AWS Lambda function URL returns a different content-length value compared to API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda that loads an S3 file and returns it as a Base64:

```
return {
    "isBase64Encoded": True,
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': b64encode(...).decode('utf-8'),
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    }
}
```

I created an API Gateway and when I call it I get:

```
<Response [200]>
Content-Type application/octet-stream
Content-Length 998356
apparent_encoding ascii
```

But calling the function URL returns:

```
<Response [200]>
Content-Type application/octet-stream
Content-Length 748765
apparent_encoding None
```

The correct `content-length` header value is the one API gateway is returning however the header is different when using the function URL even though they are both linked to the same Lambda function version & are invoking the same exact code.

What is the issue?

Comment: Seems I can have some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215424/returning-dynamic-content-type-via-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-function?rq=1

Comment: Is this S3 file always an image?

Comment: is a python pickled `pickled_data = pickle.dumps(data)` compressed an encoded, when loading through API Gateway It can be parsed and used with my python code client, but when calling the function URL, doesn't recognize the format.

Comment: this is the error when I try to parse the pickle from function URL: `blosc_extension.error: Error 140 : not a Blosc buffer or header info is corrupted`, no problem through API gateway

Comment: Are you using proxy integration on your API GW?

Comment: yes, I'm using CDK to create the resources: `new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(app, { proxy: true });`

Comment: Interesting - try not setting the content-type header manually within your code. What results do you now get for each invocation?

Comment: still same issue, now for the response the default content-type is json `Content-Type application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `isBase64Encoded` is set to `true`, the Lambda function is reversing the encoding to obtain the original data. This is why you're getting a lower `content-length` value.

However, `b64encode(...).decode('utf-8')` encodes your `body` content & then decodes it back to non-base64-encoded content. You're not actually returning base64-encoded data but you're specifying that you are.

Set `isBase64Encoded` to `false` and you should receive the correct full amount of data - as to why it works with API Gateway, it probably does an internal check, realises that you're not actually returning base-64 encoded data and returns the data as is.